# Grouping by id and looking at another column in a particular order to see if the id group satisfies a particular condition

Tags: sql

| customer_id | transaction success |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Failed |
| 2 | Complete |
| 1 | Failed |
| 1 | Complete |
| 3 | Failed |
| 2 | Failed |
| 3 | Complete |
| 3 | Failed |
| 3 | Failed |
| 3 | Complete |

Essentially I want to write a statement to identify if the customer has had a completed transaction after having had a failed transaction sometime before. So in this example, customer 1 and customer 2 would be satisfy this. Assume that there is an added timestamp column next to transaction success.

The resulting table should look like this:

| customer_id | returning_success |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | True |

Comment: How, in your sample data, do you identify "some time before"? There is nothing that defines an order to your data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is not important if the Complete was after or prior to the Cancellation, you can `LEFT JOIN` the table with a subquery that only takes the completes. If the result is `NULL`, then is not have a complete state. Otherwise is true.

As you don't provide your DBMS (Please read: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)) we take in consideration `IFNULL` but this can change in other DBMS: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

```
SELECT
yt.customer_id,
IFNULL(completes.customer_id,'false','true') as returning_success
FROM
yourtable yt
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT 
customer_id
FROM
yourTable
WHERE transaction_success = 'Complete') completes
ON completes.customer_id = yt.customer_id
```

Comment: I am using bigquery! And unfortunately order does matter...basically trying to track customers who initially had a failed transaction and came back and tried again successfully.

Comment: @mattyrcyrpto you should include the data

Answer (score 0):

If you just need customers that had had both succesfull and faild transactions, you should implement this:

```
select customer_id, case when  sum(case 
                                    when transaction='Faild'
                                    then 1 
                                    else 0 end)>0
                                and 
                                sum(case 
                                    when transaction='Complete'
                                    then 1 
                                    else 0 end)>0
                          then 'True'
                          else 'False' end 
                    returning_success
from table_
group by customer_id
```

If you actually do have some timestamp column:

```
select nvl(c.customer_id, f.customer_id) customer_id
     , case when last_complete_time is null 
                    or first_fail_time is null 
                    or first_fail_time>last_complete_time 
            then 'False'
            else 'True' end
       returning_success
from (
    select customer_id, max(time_) last_complete_time
    from table_
    group by customer_id
    where transaction='Complete'
    ) c
full join (
    select customer_id, min(time_) first_fail_time
    from table_
    group by customer_id
    where transaction='Fail' 
    ) f on c.customer_id=f.customer_id
```

You also can use this query to filter all True cases and then just union or join the rest:

```
    select f.customer_id, 'True'
    from (
        select customer_id, max(time_) last_complete_time
        from table_
        group by customer_id
        where transaction='Complete'
        ) c
    join (
        select customer_id, min(time_) first_fail_time
        from table_
        group by customer_id
        where transaction='Fail'
        ) f on c.customer_id=f.customer_id
    where first_fail_time<last_complete_time
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added a timestamp column. Please assume there is a transaction timestamp column and thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, updated my answer!